# How can i input an id into a axios request to pull specific data from backend

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, react-redux, axios

OK so kinda new here.
So currently I have data in the backend where I needed to pull it using a specific id so it gets the specific data for that user. In the backend, I just need to put it as an argument. In the front end, I'm able to pull the owner "ID" that I need to put in the argument I just don't know if I am doing it right here is my code for my front-end and server controller.also here is the pic of my logs 16 is the code for the specific user that i using [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRZf5.png)

```
class GetDogs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: "",
      dogs: []
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    //destructure get user function
    const { getUser } = this.props;
    //call function to get user info
    await getUser();
    //sets state into owner_id that i need to be put as the argument for my get dog's function
    await this.setState({ id: this.props.userReducer.user.owner_id });
    //call axios to bring dog info
    await axios
      .get(`/api/yourdogs`, {
        owner_id: this.state.id
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ dogs: response.data });
      });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.id);
    console.log(this.state.dogs);
    return <div>get dogs</div>;
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => state;

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getUser }
)(GetDogs);
```

```
module.exports = {
  newDog(req, res) {
    const db = req.app.get("db");
    const { name, age, picture, breed, sex, owner_id } = req.body;
    db.newDog([name, age, picture, breed, sex, owner_id])
      .then(response => {
        res.status(200).send(response);
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  },
  getDogs(req, res) {
    const db = req.app.get("db");
    const { owner_id } = req.body;
    db.getDogs([owner_id])
      .then(response => res.status(200).json(response))
      .catch(console.log);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing like this :

```
...
    await this.setState({ id: this.props.userReducer.user.owner_id });
    //call axios to bring dog info
    await axios
      .get(`/api/yourdogs`, {
        owner_id: this.state.id // i don't think this.state.id is already assign new value
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ dogs: response.data });
      });
...
```

so, try it like this :

```
...
  this.setState({ id: this.props.userReducer.user.owner_id }, () => {
    //call axios to bring dog info
    axios
      .get(`/api/yourdogs`, {
        owner_id: this.state.id
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ dogs: response.data });
      });
  });
...
```

Comment: pretty much everything stayed the same 16 was still put into the id state, but nothing was brought into dogs state. In my controller file, I did put 16 in the parameter to make sure function worked with my join statement and data was brought in.